# combobox value not showing in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, datatable, combobox

I get problem while loading `Combobox` value from database. I am using `SQLite` Database. It only show a single value in `Combobox` but in my database there is multiple value. So how can i do this.

This is my Code:

Class `DatabaseHandler` it has two methods which `Execute Query` and other methods return `DataTable` object:-

```
 public int ExecuteSql(String Query)
        {
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(Query, Connection);
            return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

 public DataTable GetDataTable(String Query)
          {
              SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(Query, Connection);
              SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
              DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
              dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
              return dataTable;
          }
```

This is `Category` Class and this is piece of code where i got a problem:-

```
private void CategoryName()
        {
            try
            {
                String Query = "Select CategoryName from CategoryTable;";
                databaseHandler.ExecuteSql(Query);
                DataTable dataTable = databaseHandler.GetDataTable(Query);
                ProductType.DataSource = dataTable;
                ProductType.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
            }
            catch (Exception CatID)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(CatID.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try this.
 ProductType.DisplayMember = "Value";
 ProductType.ValueMember = "Key";

Also check if the dataTable has row(s) return it possible it has empty return.

Comment: Write code please

Comment: I already tried I have use `ProductType.DisplayMember="CategoryName"`;`ProductType.ValueMember="CategoryID"`; but it shows only single value not all value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assigning a DisplayMember but not ValueMember. Please assign the DisplayValue along with ValueMember.

```
List<Country> countries = new List<Country> { new Country("UK"), 
                                     new Country("Australia"), 
                                     new Country("France") };
bindingSource1.DataSource = countries;    
comboBox1.DataSource = bindingSource1.DataSource;    
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Name";
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `comboBox1.DataSource = bindingSource1`? Otherwise you are just assigning the list to the combobox's DataSource.